# Ember Inspector giving me errors when inspecting my own ember app

Tags: ember.js

I am using ember inspector in chrome developer tools.  And trying to debug.  If I go to [Discourse's site](http://try.discourse.org) when I hover over application or any of the other items in the inspector, it highlights the item on the page.  But on my own site that I am testing, I get two errors.

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'highlightView'
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined
```

It is trying to set some DOM elements that don't exist on my site, but do on the discourse site.  Any ideas what I need to set to get this working?

Comment: Having the same problem. Issue is opened on bug trucker: https://github.com/tildeio/ember-extension/issues/11

Comment: You can try this branch https://github.com/tildeio/ember-extension/pull/6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**ember-extension** — especially master — requires the latest master for **ember** and **ember-data**, due to some features introduced that might have not gotten to a release yet.

I would recommend updating your dependencies and trying out the [latest night build](http://ember-extension.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/ember-extension-latest.zip)